# How to stop image slider after one loop using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I bought a html template in themeforest and customized. It has a slider with 3 images. I want to stop the slider after completing 1 loop.

```
<div id="slider" data-auto="true">

<div id="slide1"><img></div>
<div id="slide2"><img></div>
<div id="slide3"><img></div>

</div>
```

Now I want to change parent div's attribute to false when slide3 div loads. I'm trying this now.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#slide3").load(function(){
            $("slider").attr("data-auto", false);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: which slider you are using?

Comment: At the point of loading, you may be too late to set the data attribute. Does the library you are using have any other api methods you can call to stop the slider?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `data-auto` tag simply starts the slider automatically. try searching options like `loop:` into the js init script to disable slider looping